# IE 9 is making the input text field resizable, how to disable that and remove the border around it?

Tags: html, css

I added a text input field inside a contenteditable div in IE 9, but the input field is resizable and has a border around it, i tried to fix this with CSS but it is not working.
Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">     
    <div id="input" style="border:1px solid black;height:100px;" tabindex="0" onfocus="divFocus();" onblur="divBlur();">
        <p id="text" contenteditable="true">
        <input type="text" id="textBox" size="3" onblur="keydown(32);" onkeypress="this.style.width = ((this.value.length + 1) * 8) + 'px';" 
       value="Anything" />
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
    #textBox
{
    text-wrap:normal;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:15px;
    border:none;
    resize:none;
    border:0; 
    border-color: transparent;
}
#textBox:focus 
{
    outline: none;
    outline-width: 0;
    outline-color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
resize:none
```

this will stop the input field from resizing

Comment: I found out the problem in IE is related to contenteditable="true"
when i removed it the box disappeared and IE started to behave like other browsers.